# What exactly is the total size of the array using size in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, size

I am learning about "Numpy" and I read somewhere that to get the total size of the array we can use "size".

Below commands are what I executed :

```
print("x3 shape:", x3.shape) 

print("x3 size: ", x3.size)
```

Result :

```
x3 shape: (3, 4, 5)

x3 size: 60
```

I cannot understand why for 12 values the total size is 60.
I tried but still not able to visualize it.

Comment: Your shape is 3, 4, 5, meaning you have 3*4*5=60 elements

Comment: This is a multi-dimensional array - Imagine a 3D grid 3 elements wide, 3 deep and 5 tall - This would mean there are 3*4*5=60 elements in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In numpy `shape` is used to get the dimensional details of the array whereas `size` returns the total elements present in the array. 
In your example, the matrix is three dimensional hence its size would be `3*4*5 = 60`.